# Inspiron 5315 problems

Tags: graphics, freeze, inspiron, visual-artifacts

I'm experiencing some graphics and performance problems. Whenever I load Ubuntu, my background looks like the below photo. I'm also having some really bad performance issues, for example: when I full screen Chromium it flashes a screen, freezes and then eventually brings up the full screen. I'm also just having a ton of freezing issues in general.

I decided to bring new life to my old Windows Vista computer to use as a Plex Media Server to watch my DVD collection, but right now it's not working too well. I was thinking it might have to be a problem with the drivers?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem after I updated the kernel to the latest version. See you are on the latest one then I would suggest you downgrade it to a previous one. I mean upgrading or downgrading your kernel version. You can check the steps [here](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/).

If your problem still persists, then simply downgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. I also downgraded to it, because 18.04 has too many glitches right now. There is a new problem every day.

Comment: Any suggestion on which Ubuntu version to downgrade to? Also, you mean completely reinstall an older OS version, correct?